# Slicing Image to map different textures

Tags: opengl

In OpenGL fix function programming, can I possibly map different textures on different objects, but that texture in generated from one image only. For e.g. I have 1024 X 1024 image. I have four rectangles in my scene. Now I would want to slice image into 256 X 256 *4 and map these sliced images as textures.

How can I do this. One option is to off course pre-slice the image. But can this be done using glTexSubImage2D or some similar/different API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : Shaders are required to use array textures : http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_array.txt. I'll leave the answer as it might still be useful info.

I guess you can use an Array Texture for this : http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture

You make a 256 x 2048 texture. When loading the texture you specify a layer size (256 x 256) and layer count (4). Your texture will then be split up in four layers.

You can access the texture using UVs : `[x, y, LayerId]`

Note that if you want to generate mipmaps, you **need** to define the number of levels when you allocate the storage with `glTexStorage3D`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use texture coordinates, which indicate which parts of the texture you wish to be mapped onto your object, rather than mapping the whole thing.

Read more: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html#name6

Comment: yeah that can be another option; but i'm afraid that may not work for me. Actually how many slices to be done is not fixed, I am going to get this information on the fly, so automating task of deciding texture coordinates seems more difficult. I may be wrong though!

Comment: @Adorn I don't see why 'how many slices to be done is not fixed' prevents this from being the correct solution.

Comment: I am not saying it will not be correct; just seems complex to me.

Comment: @Adorn Just pretend you sliced the image and ask yourself, 'how far in slices into the image is my slice (in both X and Y), and how many slices wide and high is my image' and then you have enough to calculate what texture coordinates you need.

Comment: i did it with texture coordinates only. It was that hard after recognizing pattern of slicing. Thanks!

Comment: well.. i meant not that hard.. typo ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have three options.

1. Use different texture coordinates for each different rectangle.
2. Transform the texture coordinates using `glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE)` and a different matrix between drawing each rectangle.
3. Create four different OpenGL textures from your original big texture. I don't think OpenGL offers you any help here. You have to either use a paint package to do it (easiest option if you only have to do this a few times), or copy parts of the image into a new buffer before calling `glTexImage2D`.

I think the first option is the easiest, with the advantage that you don't have to change any state between drawing the rectangles.

Comment: thanks. I went ahead with option 1 only. can you give some code explanation or link of option 2?

Comment: http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mjb/cs553/Handouts/Texture/texture.pdf looks like a reasonable general discussion of textures. The transformation of texture coordinates is discussed on page 7